# Delete specific resource from a module via Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Terraform Gurus, I am trying to delete one VM from a bunch of VMs. Right now, I have two VMs but that number could vary. I am looking for the ability to delete a specific VM.
I am familiar with terraform destroy command but puzzled by why it's unable to recognize the match.
I am running the below version on Apple M1 mac

```
% terraform --version
Terraform v1.5.4
on darwin_arm64


% terraform state list |grep -i instance

module.gce_instances.google_compute_instance.demo_gce[0]
module.gce_instances.google_compute_instance.demo_gce[1]


% terraform destroy -target module.gce_instances.google_compute_instance.demo_gce[1]
zsh: no matches found: module.gce_instances.google_compute_instance.demo_gce[1]
```

Comment: I'm guessing you need something like this: `terraform destroy -target 'module.gce_instances.google_compute_instance.demo_gce[1]'`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a million @MarkoE